# Server Conflict when running two Django projects simultaneously

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on two Django project at the meantime.

However, I am not able to switch my server from one to another. When I am running the server of http://127.0.0.1:8000/, it keeps showing the old website but not able to access the new one.

I have searched for a number of solutions and I found this python package "django-livereload-server"
https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server

I followed this method strictly but it doesn't work.

The following error message was shown when I run `python manage.py runserver`

> Watching for file changes with StatReloader
>
> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified some issues:
>
> WARNINGS: ?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'admin' isn't unique. You may
> not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
>
> System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
>
> You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly
> until you apply the migrations for app(s): f lights. Run 'python
> manage.py migrate' to apply them. June 16, 2021 - 19:11:02 Django
> version 3.2.4, using settings 'airline.settings' Starting development
> server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Is it the problem of my code or what're the problems

Edit: the problem is caused by both servers are running on the default port 8000

It can be solved by running the command python manage.py runserver  Replace with an actual port number. Now both will be accessible at once on their respective ports.

Reference: https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided much information in regards to your second development server, I have to assume here.

I am assuming you are running the command `python manage.py runserver` on both applications. This will cause conflict with the original server as they will both default to port `8000`.

You can avoid this by running the command `python manage.py runserver <PORT>`
Replace  with an actual port number. Now both will be accessible at once on their respective ports.

https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server I believe this will just run your server as if in production and not solve the issue you are having, so this is incorrect for your needs.

Hope this solves your issue.